# How to prevent the creation of data readable by all customers in a Parse table?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a table called Goals with default CLP (Public read and write).

My mobile app has default ACL set so that only the owner for the data can read and write from it.

Let’s now assume that someone is able to obtain the client keys maliciously from the app, and add an entry in the table Goals without ACL using a command like that:

`curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xyx” \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 12345” \
-d "{\"name\":\"whatever\"}" \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/goals`

Now every user will load this new data, I would like to prevent that.

I assume there are two options:

1. Prevent Rest API users from writing data without ACL or with a Public ACL, perhaps with some CloudCode
2. In the app filter out the data that doesn't belong directly to that user

My question is, are the two above the only available options? Is the first option only doable with Cloud Code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try this again. I think the best solution in this case is to create a beforeSave trigger in cloud-code that sets the ACL the way you want it. With the Parse Javascript SDK, you can construct an ACL that only gives access to the user passed to it in the constructor. Something like this (untested code):

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Goal", function(request, response) {
  request.object.setACL(new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()));
  response.success();  
});
```

Note: I used [this post](https://parse.com/questions/default-acl-for-pfuser) as a reference. And [this](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-security-for-other-objects) too

Comment: Thanks but the I think PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true) does the same thing for all class. Probably my explanation wasn't very clear, what I need is to only read goals that belong to me (not public) or prevent someone with app keys access to write data with public read on... Does it make more sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any more sense. It seems like you have two objectives. For part one: Are you saying you want to "hide" goals that have public read access? For part two: are you saying you want to prevent "someone with app keys" from modifying Goals that have public read access? If so, I'm not sure that doing this with ACLs is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks @toddg for your answer. I have one goal that can be achieved from two different angles (I think :)). My goal is to make sure that users will only be able to read data that have their user ACL. This I think can be achieved in two way: put some cloud code that prevent anyone (via app or via REST API) to write data with public read, the other option is to prevent app user that has a public read ACL (I assume I can achieve that by filtering the data retrieved via the app locally to the app). Let me know if this explanation is better and I'll edit my question to improve clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding...  Is there other code that someone is writing that you do not have access to and you want to prevent their code from creating Goals that do not conform to your ACL rules? What I've written above will only allow the user who has created a Goal object to be able to read that same object. Thus, if this is done for all Goals created, then users will only be able to read data that have their user ACL.

Comment: Hi @toddg I edited the question because I think it wasn't clear enough what I meant. I hope that helps

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now.